# iOS 10 WKWebView contentEditable not scrolling

Tags: ios, scroll, contenteditable, wkwebview

Currently I'm using a `WKWebView` for editing HTML e-mails.

Until iOS 10 this was working quite good, except that you cannot set a viewport.

But now on iOS 10 I'm encountering another problem.

When typing, the `WKWebView` was scrolling to have the caret always on screen, but now on iOS 10 it is not scrolling anymore.

Maybe some of you may also have encountered this & already have a solution for it ?